how to show global asymptotic stability with $V(x)=f(x)^{T}Pf(x)$ as a lyapunov function.
consider the system $f(x)=\dot{x}$ with $f(0)=0$, $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable.
$f(x)$ can be written as $f(x)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x\sigma)x\partial\sigma$ (The first part of the assignment was to verify that statement). And
$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x)^{T}P+P\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x)\leq-I$
I used this to show $f(x)^{T}Px+x^{T}Pf(x)\leq-x^{T}x$ (no problems so far). On the next part I'm asked to use $V(x)=f(x)^{T}Pf(x)$ as a Lypunov function candidate to show global asymptotic stability. This is where I'm stuck. Here is where I'm at:

$V(0) = f(0)^{T}Pf(0)=0$
P is positive definite and therefore $V(x)=f(x)^{T}Pf(x) > 0$ for $x\neq0$
$\dot{V}(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (f(x)^{T}Pf(x)) \frac{\partial x}{\partial t}= (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x)^{T}Pf(x)+f(x)^{T}P\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x))\dot{x}$

This is where I'm stuck for the past 2 days and can't figure out how to show $\dot{V}(x)<0$

A trivial Lyapunov function would be $W(x)=x^\top P x$. In any case, if we give for granted that $f(x)\neq 0$ if $x\neq 0$, then it should be basically the chain rule, right? In your point 3 there is a notation problem, the term between parentesis should be a row vector...once this is fixed, I think you are there!

@MatteoDR Maybe it’s more than a notation problem because I’m noticing now that it looks like the term between the parenthesis in point 3 is $1x1$ and it’s multiplying a $nx1$ vector..maybe I can’t use the chain rule?

I will start with your last step:
$$\dot{V}(x)=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(x)^TPf(x)+f(x)^TP\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(x)\end{pmatrix}\dot{x}$$
Since you have:
$$\dot{x}=f(x)$$
So, substitute this into the expression:
$$\dot{V}(x)=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(x)^TPf(x)+f(x)^TP\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(x)\end{pmatrix}f(x)$$
Now, you need to exploit the condition you were given:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x)^TP+P\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x)\leq-I$$
You can rearrange this inequality as:
$$\begin{matrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x)^TPf(x)+f(x)^TP\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x)\leq-f(x)^Tf(x)\end{matrix}$$
Now, compare this with the expression for $\dot{V}(x):$
$$\dot{V}(x)=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(x)^TPf(x)+f(x)^TP\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}(x)\end{pmatrix}f(x)$$
You can see that the expression $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x)^TPf(x)+f(x)^TP\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x)$ is less than or equal to
$-f(x)^Tf(x).$Therefore:
$$\dot{V}(x)\leq-f(x)^Tf(x)$$
Since $f(x)$ is the derivative of $x$ and $x$ is not identically zero (except at $x=0),f(x)$ is nonzero except
at $x=0.$So, $f(x)^Tf(x)$ is always positive except at $x=0.$
Thus,$\dot{V}(x)$ is negative definite(or negative semidefinite), which implies that$V(x)$ is a Lyapunov
function candidate showing global asymptotic stability.
